# Pass GridView as parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, event-handling

I have code for create pop-up menu:

```
private void gridView1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        // Check whether a row is right-clicked.
        if (e.MenuType == DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMenuType.Row)
        {
            int rowHandle = e.HitInfo.RowHandle;
            // Delete existing menu items, if any.
            e.Menu.Items.Clear();
            // Add a submenu with a single menu item.
            e.Menu.Items.Add(CreateRowSubMenu(view, rowHandle));
         }
    }

    DXMenuItem CreateRowSubMenu(GridView view, int rowHandle)
    {
        DXSubMenuItem subMenu = new DXSubMenuItem("Rows");
        DXMenuItem menuItemDeleteRow = new DXMenuItem("&Delete Row",
          new EventHandler(OnDeleteRowClick));
        menuItemDeleteRow.Tag = new RowInfo(view, rowHandle);
        subMenu.Items.Add(menuItemDeleteRow);
        return subMenu;
    }
```

and for deleting selected rows in GridView:

```
void OnDeleteRowClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Delete Row?", "Deleting", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            DXMenuItem item = sender as DXMenuItem;
            RowInfo info = item.Tag as RowInfo;
            info.View.DeleteRow(info.RowHandle);

            dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)bindingSource1.DataSource);
        }
    }
```

I'd like to use `OnDeleteRowClick` method for two GridViews: master and detail. For main GridView I want to call `dataAdapter.Update` and for detail GridView `dataAdapterDetail.Update` method.

Is it possible to identify what exactly GridView (master or detail) raise pop-up event? Or is it possible to pass GridView that is raised pop-up menu as parameter to `OnDeleteRowClick` method.

Comment: You have to look for first parameter of `OnDeleteRowClick` that is  `sender`. It will tell you source from where event is generated.

Comment: @HassanNisar First parameter is of `DXMenuItem` type. It is contain some GridView parameters, but does not contain real name.

Comment: DXMenuItem is item of the popup-menu. Looking for parent of menu item should lead you to respective popup-menu and datatable.

Comment: Can't you retrieve the `Gridview.ID` from the `DXMenuItem`? If no what are the `GridView Parameters` that you can get?

Comment: @lnanikian In `Tag/View/Non-public members` there is `ViewName`. But it is "GridView" instead "MasterView" or "DetailView".

Comment: Another option is to create a new class derived from your `DXMenuItem ` where you will put your custom member with custom information like the name/Id of the gridView. Then you can work on that.